# How to fix a NoMethodError :undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I have 3 error messages which I believe all relate to one thing - me calling a method on an object that has not been defined properly.

I've checked over for typos, white spacing, syntax, naming.  I'm following the same process as other methods in this program which all tested OK.

I've narrowed the loop down and believe the issue is here:

```
def add(param)
  @param << param
```

---

Heres the code in full context:

```
class Todo

  def initialize(param)
    @param = param
  end

  def text
    return @param
  end
end

class TodoList

  def initialize
    @item_list = []
  end

  def add(param)
    @param << param
  end

  def print
    @item_list.each do |param|
      puts "* #{param.text}" #=> .text?
    end
  end
end
```

**Error Messages:**

Here are the error messages I'm trying to resolve.  As I mentioned earlier they all look to be pointing to a method I've not defined properly but I've not yet been able to work out why that may be.

1) Q1. Todo list TodoList adding todos adds a todo without raising an error
     Failure/Error: expect { todo_list.add(todo) }.to_not raise_error

```
   expected no Exception, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass> with backtrace:
     # ./questions/question_1.rb:43:in `add'
     # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:31:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) Q1. Todo list TodoList printing todos one todo prints a single todo with a bullet point
     Failure/Error: todo_list.add(todo)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
 # ./questions/question_1.rb:43:in `add'
 # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:41:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

3) Q1. Todo list TodoList printing todos many todos prints the todos, separated by newlines
     Failure/Error: todo_list.add(todo_1)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
 # ./questions/question_1.rb:43:in `add'
 # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:59:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ToDo` knows about `@param`. `TodoList` has no clue about `@param`, it only knows `@item_list`. Copy-paste problem? (It would also help if you didn't name the majority of your variables "param"; spotting errors is way easier if the code makes sense.)

Comment: Thanks, @Amadan, param = [] has solved the issue but you are right about how I have named the majority of variables.  That was originally done when I was first trying to work out how to get an object from the Todo class to the TodoList class.  That now appears to still be an issue I need to resolve so will post another question.

Comment: I would rather say `@item_list << param` instead of making another `param` variable that you're not using anywhere. Then again, I can't know. Maybe _this_ `param` will be different.

Answer (score 1):

ruby do not know what `@param` is in your TodoList class, you have to initialize it in your constructor like this `@param = []` that fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

By default instance variables are initialized to `nil`, hence the error. So in your `TodoList` class, you need to initialize `@param` to an object that can respond to `<<`, which in your own case, is an array `[]`

```rb
class TodoList
  def initialize
    @param = []
  end
end
```